# How to manage dynamic Text in a label with Playwright?

Tags: typescript, filter, label, playwright, dynamic-text

I have the following code in a Playwright Typescript test.

```
await page.goto('https://demoqa.com/');
await page.getByLabel('Optionen verwalten', { exact: true }).click();
await page.locator('label').filter({ hasText: 'Berechtigtes Interesse (32' }).locator('span').nth(2).click();
await page.locator('label').filter({ hasText: 'Berechtigtes Interesse (49' }).locator('span').nth(2).click();
await page.locator('label').filter({ hasText: 'Berechtigtes Interesse (16' }).locator('span').nth(2).click();
await page.locator('label').filter({ hasText: 'Berechtigtes Interesse (22' }).locator('span').nth(2).click();
await page.locator('label').filter({ hasText: 'Berechtigtes Interesse (40' }).locator('span').nth(2).click();
await page.locator('label').filter({ hasText: 'Berechtigtes Interesse (3 Anbieter' }).locator('span').nth(2).click();
await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Auswahl bestätigen' }).click();
```

There are multiple labels, below are two html examples:

```html
<label class="fc-preference-slider-container fc-consent-preference-container"><span class="fc-preference-slider-label">Einwilligung (77&nbsp;Anbieter)</span><span class="fc-preference-slider"><input type="checkbox" role="button" aria-label="Einwilligung (77&nbsp;Anbieter), Verwendung reduzierter Daten zur Auswahl von Werbeanzeigen" aria-pressed="false" tabindex="0" class="fc-preference-consent purpose" data-id="2"><span class="fc-slider-el"></span></span></label>
```

```html
<label class="fc-preference-slider-container fc-legitimate-interest-preference-container" for="fc-preference-slider-purpose-2"><span class="fc-preference-slider-label">Berechtigtes Interesse (32&nbsp;Anbieter)<button class="fc-help-tip" data-title="Was bedeutet ein berechtigtes Interesse?" data-full-info="Einige Anbieter bitten Sie nicht um Ihre Einwilligung, sondern nutzen Ihre personenbezogenen Daten auf Grundlage ihres berechtigten Interesses." role="tooltip" aria-label="Einige Anbieter bitten Sie nicht um Ihre Einwilligung, sondern nutzen Ihre personenbezogenen Daten auf Grundlage ihres berechtigten Interesses." tabindex="0"><i class="material-icons" data-title="Was bedeutet ein berechtigtes Interesse?" data-full-info="Einige Anbieter bitten Sie nicht um Ihre Einwilligung, sondern nutzen Ihre personenbezogenen Daten auf Grundlage ihres berechtigten Interesses." translate="no">help_outline</i></button></span><span class="fc-preference-slider"><input type="checkbox" role="button" aria-label="Berechtigtes Interesse (32&nbsp;Anbieter), Verwendung reduzierter Daten zur Auswahl von Werbeanzeigen" aria-pressed="true" tabindex="0" class="fc-preference-legitimate-interest purpose" data-id="2" id="fc-preference-slider-purpose-2" checked=""><span class="fc-slider-el"></span></span></label>
```

I want to deselect all the options which are aria-pressed="true"

The problem i have is with finding a loactor which works. The label i'm using i.e. 'Berechtigtes Interesse (32' may change, and i would like to make the code more robust.

I can use the unique locator id:

```
const slider2 = page.locator('[id$="fc-preference-slider-purpose-2"]');
```

but how do i then adjust the code to click on the associated slider?

Answer (score 1):

To start off, I would consider using regex to target the label. From what I can tell, you have a pattern that looks like `{text} ({number} {text})`:

```js
await page.locator('label')
  .filter({ hasText: /^[\w ]+\(\d+ [\w ]+\)$/ })
```

However, if you have control over the HTML, it would be much better to add a `data-testid="your-id"` attribute, then use a simplified query:

```js
await page.getByTestId('your-id')
```

Answer (score 0):

`getByLabel` works on a substring basis, which may work for your use case:

```js
import {expect, test} from "@playwright/test"; // ^1.39.0

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<input
  type="checkbox"
  role="button"
  aria-label="Berechtigtes Interesse (32&nbsp;Anbieter), Verwendung reduzierter Daten zur Auswahl von Werbeanzeigen"
  aria-pressed="true"
  tabindex="0"
  class="fc-preference-legitimate-interest purpose"
  data-id="2"
  id="fc-preference-slider-purpose-2"
  checked=""
>
</body></html>`;

test("input is selectable via partial label substring", async ({page}) => {
  await page.setContent(html);
  const label = "Verwendung reduzierter Daten zur Auswahl von Werbeanzeigen";
  await expect(page.getByLabel(label)).toBeVisible();
});
```

If you need more precision, another option is a CSS attribute selector `$` to search based on the end of the attribute value:

```js
// ...
  const input = page.locator(
    '[aria-label$="Verwendung reduzierter Daten zur Auswahl von Werbeanzeigen"]'
  );
  await expect(input).toBeVisible();
// ...
```

I'm not sure why you're using `.locator('span').nth(2)` since that doesn't reflect your HTML, but bear in mind that this isn't generally considered best practice, since it doesn't test [user-visible behavior](https://playwright.dev/docs/best-practices#test-user-visible-behavior). You may want to share more context to potentially avoid this.

Comment: Hello ggorlon, tahnks for your suggestion. I had overlooked that the second part of the text was also not unique. I have edited my entry to give more context

Comment: Can you share the HTML as text, not an image? I'd rather not re-type it all in to be able to run it. Thanks. If "I want to deselect all the options which are `aria-pressed="true"`" then why not use `[aria-pressed="true"]` as your selector, since it matches you specification 1:1? After the edit, your question is pretty different from the original and the website you included in the new question doesn't match your code, which has German. Is that the actual site?

Comment: yes i realise that now, that it's a different problem . I tried to add the html but got an edit error. I will try again, perhaps in smaller chunks. The website is correct - and german in the used language - i have locale: 'de-DE' in my playwrightconfig.ts

Comment: Got it, thanks for confirming. I'll update when I can.

Comment: html is now available

Comment: I wasn't able to get the site to load in German, so I'm not really sure which category you're automating. Can you share a runnable example with full code including the config, use English, or provide instructions to find the page you're automating? Thanks.

Comment: Hello ggorlon, sorry for the delayed response. I have used chrome as browser, with an Incognito window(as occurrs with Playwright run). The Dialoque appears automatically  after the mainpage has been loaded. https://demoqa.com/   It's an options menu for consent to share userdata . The language, german or english is irrelvant as i wish to use selectors which are idependant of the text. As you mentioned the post title is therefore inaccurate. i hope this helps. If not i can post the config. The code provided is the content of a beforeEach hook. regards kech

Comment: i used this code to get the desired result await page.locator('//*[@id="fc-preference-slider-purpose-2"]//parent::span').click();